# Detect iPhone different resolution in iOS

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am using `cocos2d` in iOS .

I am having a problem detecting the `iphone5 resolution(1136*640)`.

I am using code:

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

When we run app on iPhone simulator (4 inch), it gives screenWidth and `screnHeight-320,480` respectively.

Can anyone tell me the solution for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the screen width and height in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677716/how-to-get-the-screen-width-and-height-in-ios)

Comment: You should not use those kind of tricks, your app should accomodate any different sizes. I'm pretty sure that cocos2d already does it for you.

Comment: you are probably missing an 1136x640 default image for app startup in your resource bundle, and iOS is boxing the app to the iPhone 4 format.

Comment: @Andrea : i am pretty certain cocos2d does not. It accommodates automagically the retina/standard resolutions, but for screen size you are on your own. Thus the question is valid.

Comment: duplicate of "how to detect iPhone 5"
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446990/how-to-detect-iphone-5-widescreen-devices

Answer (score 1):

Write this code in .m file.

```
#define WIDESCREEN ( fabs( ( double )[ [UIScreen mainScreen ]bounds ].size.height-( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

Now you can know the screen size like this.

```
if(WIDESCREEN)
{
    NSLog(@"iPhone5 is here");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"iPhone4 is here");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add checks in your code for iPhone 4inch screens and 3.5 inch screens

```
CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
if(result.height == 480)
{
    // iPhone Classic
    // set your frames for classic iPhone here
}
if(result.height == 568)
{
    // iPhone 5, iPhone 5S, iPhone 5C
    // set your frames for 4 inch iPhone here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

iPhone 5 resolution is 1136*640 only. If you wanna check just Log below Code

the resolution it will give exactly (1136*640)

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
                        CGFloat screenScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
                        CGSize screenSize = CGSizeMake(screenBounds.size.width * screenScale, screenBounds.size.height * screenScale);


   NSLog(@"Screen SIze %@",NSStringFromCGSize (screenSize));




#define IS_IPHONE5          ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width >= 568 || [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height >= 568)?YES:NO

    #define IS_IPHONE4          ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width >= 480 || [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height >= 480)?YES:NO


if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {

         if(IS_IPHONE4)
             {
                         // iPhone 4        
              }
         if(IS_IPHONE5)
               {
                        // iPhone 5

               }
     }
```

Comment: Why downvoted could you say what is the mistake in this?