# iOS access main window

Tags: ios, uiview, swift3

How to access main window try this one but it is not working for me :

```
if let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate, let window = app.window {
 window.addSubview(offerView)
}
```

also i try with this way but no luck for me  :

```
 if let window =  UIApplication.shared.windows.first {

       window.addSubview(offerView)
 }
```

Note: `keyWindow` work for me but Using `keyWindow` can return a keyboard or UIAlertView window, which lie above my application window.

Here is existing question i found but that answer not working for me

[How do I get the keyWindow reference in a swift app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215462/how-do-i-get-the-keywindow-reference-in-a-swift-app)

*on my application one offer view appear from bottom of the page. that offer will be shown half of the screen*

Answer (score 1):

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
let rootViewController = appDelegate?.window?.rootViewController
```

You can also cast the `rootViewController` if its a custom class i.e.

```
let rootViewController = appDelegate?.window?.rootViewController as? YourCustomViewController
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution will be to add a property variable `window` of type `UIWindow` in `AppDelegate` and adding `rootviewcontroller` to that `window` property and accessing that `window` property wherever you need.