# How get rootViewController with iPadOS multi window (SceneDelegate)?

Tags: swift, ios13, xcode11, uiscenedelegate

I am using Xcode 11 (beta3) and building an app for iOS 13. In my project I created the delegate methods for `UIWindowSceneDelegate` declaring it in Info.plist.
Now I'm able to create multiple windows (and UIScene).

How can I access the rootViewController now I've not anymore a single window? I need it to get some reference to objects and bounds it holds.

In my AppDelegate `window is nil`, and in my ViewController (child view controller) instance I tried using `self.view.window.rootViewController` but I found out that `viewDidLoad()` is too soon (I think) and the window is still nil, works in `viewDidAppear()`, but I don't need to make this process every time the view controller appears.

What's the best practice with this new way to handle application scenes?

Here is my AppDelegate:

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession,
                     options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }
```

My SceneDelegate:

```swift
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // yes it's empty, I'm using storyboard
    }
```

Answer (score 25):

Now you have more than one rootViewController, one for each scene.
First, you have to answer which one you need at the moment of usage.

Probably you want to get one of the rootViewController of the currently active scene then you can use this:

```
        var rootVC:UIViewController? = nil
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            for scene in UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes {
                if scene.activationState == .foregroundActive {
                    rootVC = ((scene as? UIWindowScene)!.delegate as! UIWindowSceneDelegate).window!!.rootViewController
                    break
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
```

Answer (score 11):

You can access connected scenes using:

```
UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
```

As per [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/3197899-connectedscenes):

> Connected scenes are those that are in memory and potentially doing active work. A connected scene may be in the foreground or background, and it may be onscreen or offscreen.

Then you can iterate through them and try to get `UIWindowScene` from there.

```
guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
print(windowScene.windows) // This will print windows associated with the scene.
```

On the other hand, from the *view controller* you can access the `window` through the `view`:

```
self.view.window
```

Comment: `windowScene` has value only on current scene?

Comment: [This document on page 39](https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2019/212nyxqyrke8a9t/212/212_introducing_multiple_windows_on_ipad.pdf?dl=1) says there might be a few UIWindows in the same scene.

Comment: I can't believe they broke everything... now what's the top window and how can I add a UIView that stays on top of everything?

Comment: I have update the answer. Meanwhile, I wouldn't say there is a top window. There might be Foreground Active or Foreground Inactive windows. Have a look [WWDC session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/212). It covers principals behind the multi window UI. I hope you will find it useful.