# iAd banner at bottom of the app for 3.5 and 4 inch screen

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, iad

Hello I am trying to implement iAds at the bottom of my app When I change size to 3.5" screen, the iAd banner I have at the bottom of screen disappears. When I switch back to 4", the banner is back. How do I lock down the banner to display at bottom of screen regardless of screen size?

Here is my .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>

{

ADBannerView *adView;
BOOL bannerIsVisible;

NSInteger HighScoreNumber;
IBOutlet UILabel *HighScore;

}

@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL bannerIsVisible;

@end
```

this is .m file

```
@synthesize bannerIsVisible;

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
if (!self.bannerIsVisible) {

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animatedAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
    //banner is invisible
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, 560);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    self.bannerIsVisible = YES;
    [banner setAlpha:1];

}

}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
if (self.bannerIsVisible) {

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animatedAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
    //banner is visible and we moved it out of the screen due to connection issue
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -560);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    self.bannerIsVisible = NO;

   }

}


- (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:        (BOOL)willLeave
{
NSLog(@"Banner view is beginning an ad action");
BOOL shouldExecuteAction = YES;
if (!willLeave && shouldExecuteAction) {
    // stop all interactive proccess in the app
    // video pause
    //audio pause
}
return shouldExecuteAction;

}

- (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner

{

// resume everything
// video
// audio  
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

HighScoreNumber = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HighScoreSaved"];
HighScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HighScore: %li", (long)HighScoreNumber];


adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
adView.frame = CGRectOffset(adView.frame, 0, -50);
[adView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
[self.view addSubview:adView];
adView.delegate=self;
self.bannerIsVisible=NO;
[super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[adView removeFromSuperview];
adView.delegate = nil;
adView = nil;
}
```

Here is all of my code for iAds I really need help with this issue.Thanks

Comment: Check the [screen size](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5677716/643383) and position the ad view accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I had this problem recently, and I found a solution so I will post it here in case someone else stumbles upon it.

I noticed that when you change the phones for some reason the `ViewController` retained the size specified in the storyboard (in my case it was iPhone 6).

So my fix was in the `viewDidLoad` method I got the size of the main screen after it loaded, instead of the size of the actual view or frame.

Swift:

```
var screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
println(screenSize)

var viewSize = self.view.bounds
println(viewSize)
```

Objective-C:

```
CGSize sizeOfScreen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
CGSize sizeOfView = self.view.bounds.size;
```

and the corresponding output in their respective order:

`(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 568.0)
 (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0)`

I testing this on a iPhone5S which has a screen size of 320x568, but when asked for the view's bounds I got 375x667 which is the size of which I had made it in the storyboard.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score -1):

Add a `#define` to know which device uses the App :

```
#define IS_IPHONE5() ((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)
```

Next, use this `#define` to modify the offset :

```
banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, (IS_IPHONE5() ? 560.0f : 420.0f));
```

and

```
banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, (IS_IPHONE5() ? -560.0f : -420.0f));
```

Set the right value for iPhone 4" and 3.5"

Comment: And when the new devices come out you just need to update all your apps.

Comment: yep you are right, but it's not yet the case (in one month maybe ^^)

Answer (score -1):

Set the banner position at `viewWillAppear` where you can access the `self.view.bounds.size`, don't forget to add constraints or set autoResizingMask to make it "stick" to the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I hope it will work could you elaborate more by writing the code ?

Comment: I could but I believe you can do it yourself, store a reference to `adView` when you create it, add `viewWillAppear` similar as you did for `viewWillDisappear` and set the ad view position there.