# How can I detect a simulated iOS device's screen size?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, xcode6, screen-size

How can I detect a simulated device's screen size and device name when my app is running in the simulator? I'm simulating iPhone 6 & 6 Plus on iOS 8.
All answers I have tried return "simulator" as the device name, like https://github.com/duhovny/DeviceHardware, and similar ones. Thanks!

Comment: Can you make your question a bit clearer?  Tell us exactly what you want.

Comment: I'll leave it to others to close this one, but it's a likely duplicate of [How to get the screen width and height in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5677716/643383)

Comment: I think he's referring to how it appears that the values returned by `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] are wrong.  For both iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus it returns 568 for height which is clearly wrong.  Maybe a bug?

Comment: @RobertHarvey might be a year or so late, but I've done my best to edit it to what I think OP meant :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following returns a CGRect holding the size of your device's screen in points.

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

Note that the following would return the size of your screen without the status bar. Try to think of this as the frame rectangle for your application's window.

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
```

Comment: If this is the correct answer, then what does the question have to do with iOS 8 or the new iPhones?

Comment: @rmaddy perhaps nothing. I believe OP was just describing their environment (rather poorly)