# Custom navbar sizing from iphone 5 to iphone 6

Tags: ios, iphone, size, navigationbar, iphone-6

I have a custom tab bar that was optimized for the iphone 5.

```
UINavigationBar *myBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
[self.view addSubview:myBar];
```

When it on the iphone 6, part of it is cut off of course because it only goes to 320 pixels.

How do i fix this?  Is there a way to check which iphone its being ran on, and then run the pixel specified code?  I plan on putting a background image on this navbar later so it must be centered.

Comment: Set its width to the screen width instead of 320: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5678199/2274694

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it is a bad idea to hard code dimensions like this.  This will break if you rotate, or if viewed on a screen with a different size than the original iPhone screen.

Many of these controls have a default size that you can use to your advantage.  Instead of handing it a frame, consider just modifying the frame it gives you:

```
UINavigationBar *myBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];
CGRect navBarFrame = myBar.frame;
navBarFrame.size.height // returns the right size for the current OS
navBarFrame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width;
myBar.frame = navBarFrame;
```

This type of defensive coding is helpful in keeping your app laid out properly under many conditions, including when you embed this control into a parent view controller, or viewed on tomorrows larger-screened iOS devices.

All this said, are you sure you don't want a `UIToolbar`?  Typically you don't ever create your own `UINavigationBar`, as that class is just used in `UINavigationController` for you.

Comment: How would i handle the dynamic resizing of the height of the navbar as it changes for the 6 plus?

Comment: You can handle the view controller method `willTransitionToTraitCollection:withTransitionCoordinator` and check, the traits.  The navigation bar is normally smaller size when in a _compact_ height trait collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
UINavigationBar *myBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 50)];
[self.view addSubview:myBar];
```

may be this help you.