# How to set a label's preferredMaxLayoutWidth to automatic programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilabel, autolayout

I get the following errors when I attempt to set a label's **Preferred Width** to **Automatic** in a storyboard:

> Attribute Unavailable: Automatic Preferred Max Layout Width is not available on iOS versions prior to 8.0

Since I need my layout to work on both iOS 7 and 8, I was planning to do the following:

1. Set the value to **Explicit** in the storyboard.
2. On iOS 7, set the value to an explicit, computed width programatically.
3. On iOS 8, set the value to automatic programatically.

1 and 2 are easy. How do I do step 3? Is there a constant I can set it to?

---

**Here's what I have tried so far...**

If you set the value to automatic on a storyboard and you inspect `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`, you will see that it is `0`.

However, attempting to set it to 0, even if it says it is already 0, doesn't work properly (e.g. the label stays as a single line). For example, I tried setting the value to **automatic** in the storyboard, and on `viewDidLoad`, I ran the following:

```
self.label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth;
```

When I don't run the above code, the label is sized properly. However, when I run the above code (which should do nothing), it stays as a single line (undesirable behavior).

---

The header file for UILabel says:

```
// Support for constraint-based layout (auto layout)
// If nonzero, this is used when determining -intrinsicContentSize for multiline labels
@property(nonatomic) CGFloat preferredMaxLayoutWidth NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
```

As far as a constant, I couldn't find anything. The closest constant I can think of to what I want is `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, which doesn't work.

Here is what the storyboard looks like....

Automatic layout width:

```
<label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="1000" text="Foo" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="0" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Bis-iG-g4l">
    <rect key="frame" x="20" y="116" width="560" height="21"/>
    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
    <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
</label>
```

Explicit layout width:

```
<label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="1000" text="Foo" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="0" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" preferredMaxLayoutWidth="560" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Bis-iG-g4l">
    <rect key="frame" x="20" y="116" width="560" height="21"/>
    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
    <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
</label>
```

The only difference is that the latter has:

```
preferredMaxLayoutWidth="560"
```

Comment: For reference there is a related thread on the Apple developer forms: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1061142#1061142

Answer (score 8):

I haven't figured out a way to do this programmatically, but there is a pretty decent workaround.

Any valid workaround must meet these requirements:

- Use automatic [preferredMaxLayoutWidth](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/preferredMaxLayoutWidth) on iOS 8, and explicit on iOS 7.
- Must not have warnings.

The **only** way to set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` to **automatic is via a storyboard**, so we do so.

In order to suppress the above warning, **set the number of Lines to 1**.

Now, programmatically, do the following:

```
self.label.numberOfLines = 0;
if (iOS8) {
    ; // do nothing, it will use automatic via the storyboard
} else {
    self.label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = screenWidth - 32;
}
```

For reference, here is [how to find out the iOS version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/how-to-check-ios-version), and here is how to get the [screen width](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5678199/35690). Note that you must specifically look for iOS 8 and not whether or not the object responds to `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`, since that property was added in iOS 6.