# Setting label's maxPreferredLayoutWidth to automatic programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

There's an option in StoryBoard to set the `Preferred Width` to automatic 
[image]

How can this be achieved programmatically? I know that UILabel has a `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` property, but how can I set to automatic?

Comment: Yes but how can i set it to automatic?

Comment: see this once it may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27711853/how-to-set-a-labels-preferredmaxlayoutwidth-to-automatic-programmatically

Answer (score -1):

there is a property in UILabel class

```
// Support for constraint-based layout (auto layout)
// If nonzero, this is used when determining -intrinsicContentSize for multiline labels
@property(nonatomic) CGFloat preferredMaxLayoutWidth NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
```

if you will not set it will set automatically by default

Comment: I am aware, but how do I go about letting the system calculate it automatically?

Comment: if you will not set it will set automatically by default