# UIcollection in 4 equals part - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I’m trying to make UICollection with 4 items which take all the place on the screen (then divide the screen automatically in 4 part : 2 x 2).

How can I do it ?

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do it ?

The simple solution is to use the normal flow layout with 4 cells that are each about 1/4 the size of the screen. (You should actually be thinking about the window now, not the screen itself, so that your app will work correctly with split view.) `UICollectionView` lets you control the cell size and the borders between cells, so just [figure out how much space you have](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5678199/643383) and use that to calculate the cell size.