# How to change UITableViewCell based on height of iPhone model?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I am using a UITableViewController in my app. This works great, but I was wondering how I can do some small changes per device. The UITableViewCell height is not on all devices great. On iPhone 6/7 and Plus models it fits perfect, but on an iPhone SE/5 and 4 the rows are too big. I know that Interface Builder has a function called `Vary of Traits`, but when I select for example iPhone 4 and change the height of the UITableViewCell it will also be applied to all other sizes. So is this - different cell heights for different devices - possible and if yes, how can I add different cell heights based on different device heights?

Comment: Don't base anything on the device model. Calculate the row height based on the height of the table view or its parent view.

Answer (score 1):

`UITableView` has a delegate method called `heightForRowAt indexPath:`

Within that method, you can write logic that defines the cell height as a proportion of screen height, tableView height, or whatever you need

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return // screenHeight (or tableViewHeight) / someNumberThatFitsYourNeeds
}
```

Comment: And can you also tell me how to select for example only iPhone 4 or SE for an specific height?

Comment: just check if screen height is equal to the height of the iPhone 4 / SE screens...if it is, return the desired cell height

Comment: Is there a property that holds these heights of iPhones?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677716/how-to-get-the-screen-width-and-height-in-ios

Comment: that's how to get the current device height. There is no property that holds the heights of other phones, you have to hard code it

Comment: No, do not hard code anything. Do not worry about device model. Simple base the row height on the height of the table view or the view controller's view.

Comment: suggested that in the answer

Answer (score 0):

you can calculate height of cell at runtime in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat{
}
```

**for Example :**
let's assume that perfect cell height is 70 on Iphone 7 of view height 700,so you will code like

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat{
        return self.view.frame.size.height * 0.1
}
```

so using this method your cell will always size 10% of your view's height