# How can I get the correct screen size of device in UITest?

Tags: swift, xcode

In UITest, I have tried to check the device screen size, but this code doesn't get correct  size.

```swift
let boundsHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
```

When I try with above code on Xcode simulator, boundsHeight is 480 each time, regardless of the device even though it should be 568 with iPhone SE.

What causes UITest not to get the size correctly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the screen width and height in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677716/how-to-get-the-screen-width-and-height-in-ios)

Comment: I have got correct screen size with following code. `let frame = XCUIApplication().windows.element(boundBy: 0).frame.size`